# RestSharp throws NullReferenceException on server down

Tags: c#, restsharp

I have a simple part of a code:

```
try
{
    this.client.ExecuteAsync<Answer>(request, response =>
        {
            if (response.ResponseStatus == ResponseStatus.Completed)
                callback(response.Data);
            ...
        });
}
catch (WebException ex) {...}
```

and it throws **NullReferenceException** in the if line, because the response is null.
What can I do to get a message about server down?

Comment: Try http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add in a null check for your `response`:

```
try
{
    this.client.ExecuteAsync<Answer>(request, response =>
        {
            if (response != null && response.ResponseStatus == ResponseStatus.Completed)
                callback(response.Data);
            else
            {
               // add logic here to handle bad case
            }
        });
}
catch (WebException ex) {...}
```

Comment: I tried this, but I still wonder if there is any way to get proper exception at this specific case.